# Json to CSV conversion in .Net core

Tags: json, csv

I have a json string which I have to convert to CSV file.And call an external Python Service which takes the CSV file as input.What should be the approach and how to implement the same?

Edit - the python service takes input as CSV file. All I have in my C# code , is CSV string . How can I pass it as a CSV file to Python API?

Comment: If you already got the CSV string then what is the question? How to write a string to a file? But what would be the language then: C#/F#/VB?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Fravadona yes, the python service takes input as CSV file. All I have in my C# code , is CSV string . How can I pass it as a CSV file to Python API?

Comment: Well, you have to create a temporary file whose content is the CSV string and pass it to your python script. It would be better if the python script could read from stdin instead of a file, so you wouldn't even need to create the temporary CSV file.